# Where to find the existing package installed in the google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I want to check if some packages are installed in the `Colab`. What is specific folder for storing the installed packages (e.g., `keras`)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `pip` tool to list installed Python packages and their locations on the system:

```sh
!pip list -v | grep [Kk]eras
# Keras                    2.2.5           /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages pip      
# Keras-Applications       1.0.8           /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages pip      
# Keras-Preprocessing      1.1.0           /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages pip      
# keras-vis                0.4.1           /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages pip
```

Note that in Colab and other Jupyter notebook frontends, the `!` character is used to execute a shell command.

Comment: can i do something like `len(pip list)` to see how many packages there are ?

Comment: You could do `!pip list | wc`, the current output is `407     814   14844` which indicates there are 407 lines in the output, which means 407 installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to find the package, you might have probably downloaded the package instead of installing it.

Incorrect command:

```
!pip download transformers
```

Correct command:

```
!pip install transformers
```

Next, in order to find the package run the following command:

```
!pip show transformers
```